# Ladder on a Hot Tin Roof

Tags: trigonometry

I'm building a ladder to place on a roof with a 5/12 (22.6-degree) pitch and since the ladder will lean against a wall, it will lean 15 degrees (orthogonally to the pitch). The width of the ladder is 1 unit.

How much longer than the uphill leg should I make the downhill leg? I'm sure it's more than .416 unit (tan(22.6) x width). Probably not MUCH more.

Comment: It isn't clear (to me) what you mean by the uphill leg or downhill leg. Could you include a picture?

Answer (score 0):

The vertical distance the longer leg must extend is $\tan(22.6^{\circ}) \approx 0.416$. Let's call this $a$.

Since the ladder is at a $15^{\circ}$ angle with the wall, we know that the actual additional length to the longer ladder leg, say $b$, satisfies:

$\dfrac{a}{b} = \cos(15^{\circ}) \approx 0.966$

Therefore, $b = \dfrac{a}{\cos(15^{\circ})} \approx \dfrac{416}{966} \approx 0.431$ units.

Comment: This great (sorry for breaking the rule against saying that)! **And** I have a further question: now that I have the length (what I **needed**), I'm curious about something: is it possible to calculate the angle formed by the (either) leg of the ladder and the plane of the roof (the answer would be the same for both legs)? How would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

All right - by dint of extensive poaching on other Web sites, I've developed the vectors of the ladder leg(s) and of the (plane of) the roof, and what I get is **$68.23^{\circ}$**, a credible difference ($0.85^{\circ}$) from the $67.38^{\circ}$ the ladder would form with the roof if the ladder were vertical. This result is **derived from** the answer to my first question provided above by David Wheeler.

If anyone would address my further question, I'd appreciate confirmation or refutation.